# What's the difference between うたがう (疑う) and うたぐる (疑る)?

Tags: word-choice

What's the difference between 疑う{うたがう} and 疑る{うたぐる}?

It seems that うたぐる is not common, but I'm not sure.

How should I read 疑って?

Comment: Some more context might be helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One sounds formal and it is kosher with most dictionaries, Utagau, while the latter, うたぐる, is more casual and actually two words put together in a slang-y way. I guess I could pull "Guesstimate" as an analogy - where Guess and Estimate are lumped together for a funny, casual effect. The same thing is going here. うたぐる is うたがう and　かんぐる (go on a limb and hazard a guess, often on a personal matter) smushed together for a funny effect.

Though, it WAS funny in the turn of the 19th century and the funny factor is lost today. Only the word and usage as a synonym to うたがう remains.

Do a google search on words to see usage. With うたがう you will hit more news articles like "The suspect has been arrested on suspicion of theft" 容疑者は窃盗の疑い（うたがい）で警察に逮捕されました。whereas うたぐる might hit someone's rant on their personal blog.